# How long does a Suggestion last, after the spell is over, in the NPCs head?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, curse-of-strahd

I'm aware that the *[Suggestion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/suggestion)* spell could last up to 8 hours or until the task is performed. However, take this scenario as an example.

I'm running *Curse of Strahd* for my group. They just made it to Vallaki with Ismark and Ireena in tow. They walked through the town square, saw Izek with guards, and comically went over to him to ask questions. Shortly into the awkward conversation, Izek noticed Ireena and immediately wanted to take her away for "questioning." The wizard in the group then cast *Suggestion* and told Izek, "There's no need to take her." Izek failed his save so he agreed and went about his business replacing the old posters.

This is an interesting scenario for me because *Suggestion* worked but the wizard didn't word it in a way that would last long (in my opinion). So at what point in time would it dawn on Izek that Ireena is in town and that he should arrest her? Would he need to see her again?

I have an idea in my head how this is going to play out but wanted others' take on it. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, but that's more than okay! Different ways of asking the same question are good to help other find answers. If you don't think it is, please let us know what's different.

Comment: More than ever I would encourage people looking at this duplicate to remember that accepted answers are just what helped the person posting the question the most, and that reading all the other answers is always good.